# Magento 2 API - Create shipping not updating order status

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using the Magento 2 API call for creating shipments (/V1/shipment).

The shipment gets created in magento successfully, but the order status does not get moved to complete as I would expect.

My JSON request is as below:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "billingAddressId": 4,
        "comments": [],
        "items": [
            {
                "orderItemId": 2,
                "qty": 2
            }
        ],
        "orderId": 2,
        "shippingAddressId": 3,
        "totalQty": 2,
        "tracks": []
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is already a known bug in Magento as per [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3307)